# Connecting to Back4App from Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, back4app

Not able to connect to back4App.

I am following the steps from [back4App](https://www.back4app.com/docs/xamarin/xamarin-tutorial) 
I am able to get the App running in emulator. However, I don't see anything in Back4App dashboard.

Login at Back4App.
Find your app and click on Dashboard.
Click on Core.
Go to Browser.

I don't see installation under Core -> Database-browser.

I verified many times the applictionID and .NET key.
Tried to put try/catch around SaveAync code, but I don't see any exception. Stuck here.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Support.V7.AppCompat;

using Parse;

namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


            ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration
            {
                ApplicationId = GetString(Resource.String.back4app_app_id),
                WindowsKey = GetString(Resource.String.back4app_dotnet_key),
                Server = "https://parseapi.back4app.com"
            });


            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


            ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation.SaveAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I expect installation folder to be created in Back4App.

Comment: Can you please change it to `await ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation.SaveAsync();` add a try/catch around it and check if there is any exception?

Comment: I have already tried that.

Comment: Can you try to get a Verbose application out log, and share it as a Pastebin or something, so we can see what the logs are telling you

Comment: I wasn't waiting long enough to capture exception. Here it is. e = {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  
at Parse.Internal.HttpClient+<>c__DisplayClass15.<ExecuteAsync>b__d 
(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00093] in 
<5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
  at Sy..

Comment: It also seems from the exception, that the library uses "Parse.Internal" from a library (by parseplatform.org) bought and then sunset by Facebook. It also seems that the Back4App Github repo is old, https://github.com/back4app/xamarin-quickstart-example/

Comment: Hi Bish, I kindly ask you to check the link below, it's a sample project that might help you with that:

https://github.com/templates-back4app/xamarin-helloworld/blob/35c60b94c1a8c6f40cfb7ed18aa6315a79c14b28/HelloWorldParseServer/HelloWorldParseServer.Android/MainActivity.cs

Comment: Getting the same issue with the attached sample.

Comment: Can you point out which line is throwing the null reference exception?

Comment: `await ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation.SaveAsync()`                                        
 is giving error. `e = {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Parse.Internal.HttpClient+<>c__DisplayClass15.<ExecuteAsync>b__d (System.Threading.Tasks.Task 1[TResult] t) [0x00093] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0`

Comment: It worked on a real phone. On emulator it crashes. I would guess the emulator has connectivity issues with internet.

Answer (score 0):

It worked on a real phone. On emulator it crashes. I would guess the emulator has connectivity issues with internet.